# Changings Graphics drawString Color

Tags: java, graphics, fonts, colors

I am trying to create a font from a ttf file and then render it as a certain colour to the screen using Graphics2D.

The font loads fine and renders to the screen as the correct font, HOWEVER the colour of the text stays black. How can I change the colour of the text to be white or another colour? Any help is appreciated!

Getting the font:

```
    public Font getFont(String name) {
        Font font = null;
        if (name == null) {
            font = new Font("sans", Font.PLAIN, 24);
        }

        try {
            String fname = "assets/fonts/" + name;
            File fontFile = new File(fname);
            font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontFile);
            GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            ge.registerFont(font);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return font;
    }
```

Drawing the text:

```
    Font title = getFont("PressStart2P.ttf");
    g2.setFont(title.deriveFont(30.0f));
    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2.drawString("A Game of Squares", 50, 80);
```

Comment: `setColor()` should work. You don't need to say `new Color()`. Just the constant should work.

Comment: It works find for me.  An actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses

Answer (score 4):

The issue lies here:

```
    g2.setColor(new Color(Color.WHITE));
```

The Color class in Java does not accept another Color object as an input for its constructor, because Color.WHITE (along with a myriad of other predefined colors) is a reference to a Color object, the line should read:

```
    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake while retyping my code. I originally had it as new Color(0xFFFFFF) but changed it to Color.WHITE for simplicity. g2.setColor(Color.WHITE); does not work either.

Comment: @Brendan I did my own test and it works fine, maybe you should consider providing an actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses

Comment: Any chance we could see a more complete version of your paint(Graphics g) method there? I've set up a boilerplate JFrame and added your getFont(String name) method, pasted what's given of the drawing code into the paint(Graphics g) method, and even used the same font as you, but the font is changing color on my end, which points to a problem earlier in your paint(Graphics g) method, or possibly even the text being draw over later in black.

Comment: Actually it appears to be working fine... for any colour but white, which was unfortunately the only colour I tested...

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me...

Some notes:

1. I've used the font as an embedded resource, but it shouldn't make a difference (ps- Tested (as external resource), all is fine)
2. Avoid loading resources in the `paint` methods, this will slow your painting process.  Paint methods should return as quickly as possible

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class FontTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FontTest();
    }

    public FontTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Font font;

        public TestPane() {
            font = getFont("PressStart2P.ttf");
            font = font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 30);
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(1000, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            String text = "All your base are belong to us";
            g2d.setFont(font);
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            int x = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
            int y = ((getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();
            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2d.drawString(text, x, y);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        public Font getFont(String name) {
            Font font = null;
            if (name == null) {
                font = new Font("sans", Font.PLAIN, 24);
            }

            try {
                String fname = "/assets/fonts/" + name;
                font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, getClass().getResourceAsStream(fname));
                GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
                ge.registerFont(font);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return font;
        }
    }

}
```